# Get next node in nodequeue

Tags: paging, navigation, nodes

I have a nodequeue named `work_order`.

If I am in a page which belongs to this queue, is there a way I can get the next node that will be there in the nodequeue?

I looked at most of their API functions, but I did not find one that does this.

I am using drupal 7

Comment: Are you talking about the module named Nodequeue or the queue for cron jobs?

Comment: @Paul module named nodequeue

Answer (score 2):

Should be something like getting the nid of the current node and then being $nid the node id of the current node and $sqid the queue id:

```
$pos = nodequeue_queue_position('work_order', $nid);
$nodes = nodequeue_load_nodes($sqid, FALSE, $pos+1, 1, TRUE);
```

It's untested so maybe you need to tweak the position and so.

Comment: sorry, but what is `$sqid` here?

Comment: It should be the id of your nodequeue, "work_order"

Comment: I have a valid `$nid`. In the nodequeue admin section my queue's machine name is `work_order`. However when I pass both to `node_queue_position`, I get `$pos` empty...

Answer (score 0):

My solution is bit different from pcambra's. Actually I implement looking for previous and next node like this:

```
$pos = (int)nodequeue_get_subqueue_position($sqid, $node->nid);
$node_prev = nodequeue_load_nodes($sqid, FALSE, $pos - 2, 1);
$node_next = nodequeue_load_nodes($sqid, FALSE, $pos, 1);
```

Note: The previous is $pos-2, not $pos-1. The reason is that the returned position of nodequeue_get_subqueue_position is starting from 1, and the argument of position in nodequeue_load_nodes is from 0! The same reason for the next node.

Finally, the node you got is stored in the returned array. For example you can retrieve its nid like this:

```
$next_node_nid = $node_next[0]->nid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using custom_pagers module.

https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_pagers

It actually quite simple once you apply the needed patches as the module is not well maintained.

https://www.drupal.org/node/262854

apply these patches -

https://www.drupal.org/node/1288368#comment-6429832
https://www.drupal.org/node/1346194#comment-5881226

Now, just enable the module, create a new custom pager
pager position : sideblock
pager node list : view >> nodequeue_#

to get the correct nodequeue - admin/structure/nodequeue
just hover over the edit link to get the machine id