# Next in position of nodequeue in views

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I got A Drupal7 setup with module view and nodequeue.
Now i want a pager on the bottom of my content-type that gets me to the next node of this type in my nodequeue position.

Now i found this [Get next node in nodequeue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/123485/get-next-node-in-nodequeue) when i googled it.
But this solutions wont work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like that with [Custom Pagers](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_pagers) module in the past.

I was hoping I could achieve the same thing with views and contextual filters but I can't figure it out.